# Java trouble checking if password string is valid

Tags: java, string, passwords, boolean

So I'm trying to get this to take user input as a string and check the password to make sure of these two things:

1. The password is a minimum of 8 characters.
2. The password only contains letters and numbers.

Now the problem is this:
Checking the password for a minimum of 8 characters works, but checking it to make sure it only contains letters and numbers does not work. It simply terminates without giving a single message if the minimum amount of numbers/letters are entered. **However if it sees a character that is not a letter or number, it will print out this**:

Please enter a password: ###

Password can only contain letters and numbers.

Password can only contain letters and numbers.

Password can only contain letters and numbers.

Password accepted!

**What it should output is this:**

Please enter a password: ###

Password can only contain letters and numbers.

or

Please enter a password: test1234

Password accepted!

```
    password.java    
    package Password;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Password {

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    boolean valid = true;
    System.out.println("Please enter a password:");
    String password = input.nextLine();
    int i = 0;
    //declares i as the counter varible to control the loop and initializes it to 0

    if((password.length( ) < 8 )) //check the passwords length and make sure it's a minimum of 8 characters
    {
    System.out.println("Password must have at least 8 characters.");
    valid = false;
    }
    //loops the code below it for the length of i until the password length is reached
    while(i < password.length())
    {
    if ((password.charAt(i)>='a' && password.charAt(i)<='z') ||  (password.charAt(i)>='A' && password.charAt(i)<='Z') ||(password.charAt(i)>='0' && password.charAt(i)<='9'))
    //loop through all the characters in the string entered and make sure they only consist of letters and numbers
       valid = true;
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Password can only contain letters and numbers.");  
        valid = false;
    }
    i++;
    //add an iteration to the loop
    }

    if(!valid == true)
    System.out.println("Password accepted!");
    }
    }
```

Any help at all with this would be great.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674449/checking-password-code ?

Comment: Once you've found an invalid character, you should set valid to false and break out of the loop. Otherwise you risk setting the flag valid to true again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify the code a bit, first start with `valid` by checking the `password.length()`; then test each character in the password (stopping if any are invalid). Then finally check if the password was valid before displaying your accepted message. Like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a password:");
String password = input.nextLine();
boolean valid = password.length() >= 8;

if (!valid) {
    System.out.println("Password must have at least 8 characters.");
} else {
    for (char ch : password.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(ch) && !Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            System.out.println("Password can only contain letters and numbers.");
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (valid) {
    System.out.println("Password accepted!");           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the main error in this check code is the while loop,when you see a wrong character there is no need to continue the loop,simply you do this kind of checks in that way :

```
String toCheck;       //the string to check some criteria 
boolean valid = true; // we assume that nothing wrong happen till now

for(int i=0;i<toCheck.length();i++){ //loop over the characters
    if(/*condition of wrong case*/){ 
        valid = false;               //mark that something wrong happen
        break;                       //exit the loop no need to continue
    }
 }

 if(valid){
    //nothing wrong happen
 } else {
    //something wrong happen
 }
```